# If statement that performs segue with UIPicker

Tags: arrays, swift, iphone, if-statement, arraylist

I am building an app where at a certain question I am able to use a UIPicker to go back to go back to previous questions, however I either get an error or nothing happens when attempting to use the app.

Also, all of my pages Storyboard ID is the name I am calling them for the segue.

I have tried using a switch statement but I get too many errors so I have decided that if statements might go better.

Old Switch Statement:

```
    public func textFieldDidEndEditing(_ textField: UITextField) {

    let row = picker.selectedRow(inComponent: 0)

    switch (row) {

    case 0: storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "Q1") as? Q1; performSegue(withIdentifier: "Q1", sender: self)
    break;
    case 1: storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "Q2") as? Q2; performSegue(withIdentifier: "Q2", sender: self)
    break;
    case 2: storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "Q3") as? Q3; performSegue(withIdentifier: "Q3", sender: self)
    break;
    case 3: storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "Q4") as? Q4; performSegue(withIdentifier: "Q4", sender: self)
    break;
    case 4: storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "Q5") as? Q5; performSegue(withIdentifier: "Q5", sender: self)
    break;
    case 5: storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "Q6") as? Q6; performSegue(withIdentifier: "Q6", sender: self)
    break;
    default: break;
}
}
```

The error I get is 'Use of undeclared type "Q1"'

I am trying to do something along the lines of,

```
func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, didSelectRow row: Int, 
inComponent component: Int) {
        DiffQuestion.text = data[row]

        if (data == "Q1") {
        storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "Q1") as? Q1; 
    performSegue(withIdentifier: "Q1", sender: self)
       }
    }
```

Current error is on my if-statement "Binary operator '==' cannot be applied to operands of type '[String]' and 'String'"
I know I probably structured it wrong, I'm still very new to all of this.

UPDATE: 
I currently have it written as:

```
func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, didSelectRow row: Int, inComponent component: Int) {
    DiffQuestion.text = data[row]

    if (data[row] == "Q1") {
        storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "Q1"); performSegue(withIdentifier: "Q1", sender: self)
    }
    if (data[row] == "Q2") {
        storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "Q2"); performSegue(withIdentifier: "Q2", sender: self)
    }
    if (data[row] == "Q3") {
        storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "Q3"); performSegue(withIdentifier: "Q3", sender: self)
    }
    if (data[row] == "Q4") {
        storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "Q4"); performSegue(withIdentifier: "Q4", sender: self)
    }
    if (data[row] == "Q5") {
        storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "Q5"); performSegue(withIdentifier: "Q5", sender: self)
    }
    if (data[row] == "Q6") {
        storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "Q6"); performSegue(withIdentifier: "Q6", sender: self)
    }
```

Q6 gets a transition as does Q4, but everything else just gives me "Thread 1: SIGABRT"

Debug area says:

Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: 'Receiver () has no segue with identifier 'Q5''

Comment: based on your last debug message. It says there is no segue with identifier Q5, have you made sure this segue is in fact set up properly?

Comment: @JulianSilvestri I'm pretty sure it's been done it properly, I've named both the Storyboard ID from the page appropriatly, and just a regular segue from one page to another with the same ID and I get the same error that it doesn't have that identifier. Even though the page that works (Q6) is done the same way with no avail.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is here

```
if (data == "Q1") { // == can't be used to compare String and [String]
```

Replace with

```
if data[row] == "Q1" { }
```

---

Also you should either create and use a segue with only

```
performSegue(withIdentifier: "Q1", sender: self)
```

**OR**  present/push

```
 let vc =  storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "Q1") as? Q1
 // present or push vc
  self.present(vc, animated: true, completion: nil)
/// or push
 self.navigationController?.pushViewController(vc, animated: true)
```

Comment: Okay I tried both of these options, The first one (with performSegue) ends up giving me a the error Thread 1: signal SIGABRT. And the second one gives me the same "Use of undeclared type 'Q1'". I believe this is because the identifier is called from the storyboard ID but I wouldn't know how to make this better.